# Creation of a list with array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, group-by

I am making a query to multiple tables and as a result I get the results similar to the following list:

```
[{
    "$id": "7",
    "idPoiType": 43,
    "latPoint": 40.522053118634076,
    "lngPoint": -3.665313720703125
},
{
    "$id": "8",
    "idPoiType": 43,
    "latPoint": 40.52172689430316,
    "lngPoint": -3.6571168899536133
}]
```

I try to create from the first list, a second list with the following format

```
[{
    "idPoiType": 43,
    "point": [{40.522053118634076, -3.665313720703125}, {40.52172689430316, -3.6571168899536133}]
}]
```

for this I have two models and the following query

**Models**

```
    public class ChildPoints
    {
        public double latPoint { get; set; }
        public double lngPoint { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootPoints
    {
        public int idPoiType { get; set; }
        public List<ChildPoints> point { get; set; }
    }
```

**Query**

```
        var result1 = (
        from p in result
        group p by new
        {
            p.idPoiType,
        } into g
        select new RootPoints()
        {
            idPoiType = g.Key.idPoiType,
            point = (from p2 in g
                     select new ChildPoints()
                     {
                         latPoint = p2.latPoint,
                         lngPoint = p2.lngPoint
                     })
        }
        ).ToList();
```

**Error**

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error   CS0266  No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' en 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión) WebApplication1

How can I make the correct query so that I do not get an error or is there any other way to get the second list without the query?

Comment: Can you please translate the error message to English and also tell us which line gives the exception?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0266

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, whereas `RootPoints.point` is a `List<T>`. And though every `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, the converse is not true.

You can fix this by adding another `ToList`:

```
var result1 = (
     from p in result
     group p by new
     {
         p.idPoiType,
     } into g
     select new RootPoints()
     {
         idPoiType = g.Key.idPoiType,
         point = (from p2 in g
                  select new ChildPoints()
                  {
                      latPoint = p2.latPoint,
                      lngPoint = p2.lngPoint
                  }).ToList() // << here
     }
     ).ToList();
```

By the way, most people use conventions where property names are capitalized and class names are singular, unless they are collections of things:

```
public class ChildPoint
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public class RootPoint
{
    public int IdPoiType { get; set; }
    public List<ChildPoints> Points { get; set; }
}
```